# Comparando-se com classe DateTime, a função date é mais performática?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, desempenho, data

É muito comum ler alguns tutoriais ou artigos dizendo que programar Orientado ao Objetos pode custar mais (falo em relação à memória).

Desde que comecei a programar fica aquele pequeno comichão na mente, dizendo "Usar objeto é mais pesado que usar função".

Um exemplo que as vezes fico me questionando é se realmente é necessário usar a classe `DateTime` quando já se tem `date`.

Por exemplo:

```
echo new (DateTime('+3 days'))->format('d/m/Y');

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 days'));
```

Levando em consideração a programação orientada a objetos em PHP em relação à procedural, é correto afirmar que `date` é mais performático que  `DateTime`? Eu deveria realmente me preocupar com isso?

Comment: Se você não tem um motivo claro para se preocupar com a performance (com base em um teste de performance por exemplo), evitar o objeto será considerado uma microotimização e, portanto, supérflua e propensa a piorar a legibilidade do código. Se usar o objeto lhe traz benefícios, prefira o objeto.

Comment: Assim como se o objeto não traz nenhum benefício, não o use :) Nem mesmo por performance, se fosse o caso do objeto ser mais rápido, o que não é.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters "Usar objeto é mais pesado que usar função" tire isso da sua cachola, use os padrões de projeto, use coerência de código, no exemplo citado a `classe DateTime` traz inúmeras vantagens em relação a `date` e sinceramente todo e qualquer resposta não vai convencer que um é melhor do que o outro, teste de exaustão só traz prejuízo conceitual principalmente com esse aspecto, garanto se não vai instânciar **10000** `classes Datetime`. Só um posicionamento de um desenvolvedor que utiliza isso a muito tempo ...

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando uma VM com 512 de RAM e 1 (um) núcleo de processamento (i7),  Debian 8 64bits, Apache 2.4 e PHP 5.6, fiz o seguinte teste, considerando a mesma implementação utilizada na pergunta:

Utilizando **DateTime::createFromFormat**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('+3 days'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Resultado:

> Tempo: 3.509903 s

E também utilizando **date**:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3 days'));
}
```

Resultado:

> Tempo: 1.755909 s

Logo, parece que `date` é mais rápido que `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Com a implementação utilizando o DateTime possui o `createFromFormat`, resolvi simplificar mais o código para a comparação ser mais coerente.

**Simplificando a requisição e aumentando as requisições:**

**Chamando `date` 1.000.000 vezes:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $tmp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}
```

> Tempo: 7.605172 s

**Chamando `New DateTime` 1.000.000 vezes:**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $tmp = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}
```

> Tempo: 12.230210 s

**Cálculo do tempo:**

O tempo foi calculado pegando o tempo inicial e final com `getTime();` depois calculando:

```
$execTime = $finalTime - $time; 
echo number_format($execTime, 6) . ' s';
```

Claro que o tempo de execução irá variar de ambiente para ambiente, mas o que está sendo levado em consideração aqui é qual a melhor performance entre as duas implementações.

Deste modo, pode-se concluir que a implementação utilizando `date` é mais rápido que utilizando a classe `DateTime`

Lembrando que velocidade não é tudo. A utilização de cada uma vai depender de cada situação.

Comment: Como você contabilizou o tempo do resultado?

Comment: Pegando o tempo inicial e final com getTime(); depois calculando: $execTime = $finalTime - $time;
echo number_format($execTime, 6) . ' s';

Comment: @ViniciusMaia eu ia perguntar o mesmo. Além disso era bom saber qual o as configurações do seu sistema.

Comment: @ViniciusMaia, VM com 512 de RAM e 1 (um) núcleo de processamento (i7),  Debian 8 64bits, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.

Comment: Na resposta que postei citei o seu nome e os testes da sua resposta. Um ponto chave que acho equivocado no seu teste com `DateTime` é o mal uso. Obviamente que usando de forma inapropriada e, pior que isso, sem de fato usar os recursos da classe, trará resultados ruins. Exemplo, está criando as instâncias múltiplas vezes a cada iteração. Só precisa de uma instância. E também o fato de usar `strtotime('+3 days')` o qual aumenta o consumo de tempo e sequer faz parte da classe. Se é para testar mesmo, use os recursos da classe. Demonstrei isso na minha resposta.

Comment: Boa observação, Daniel. Isso realmente faz uma grande diferença. Ele poderia usar o new DateTime apenas uma vez e em seguida, dentro do loop, usar o ->modify ("+1 day")

Comment: @ViniciusMaia: o propósito da resposta foi testar a performance entre um método e outro... não foi escrever o código da forma mais eficiente.

Comment: O propósito é claro, Allan. O problema é que ficou vago induzindo a algo equivocado pois no mundo real não se usa dessa forma. Um objeto serve para reutilização de processos. Aí no caso está praticamente matando o objeto, usando-o como uma função procedural qualquer.

Comment: Allan o @DanielOmine tem razão, ainda por cima o AP fala mesmo em programação orientada a objetos e nesse caso a tua resposta é um bocado enganadora, que não se usa assim em OO.

Comment: devias também dizer na tua resposta como calculas os tempos de execução.

Comment: @JorgeB., hoje a tarde vou dar uma revisada e melhorar esta resposta.

Answer (score 3):

É óbvio que um recurso que consome mais memória sempre será mais custoso.

Quanto mais código, mesmo que seja uma vírgula a mais, já consome mais memória.

Exemplo:

Teste1

```
<?php

//
```

Teste2

```
<?php


//
```

O Teste2 consome mais recursos simplesmente por ter uma quebra de linha a mais. Claro que aqui não estamos considerando cache.

Com base nisso, imagine a comparação entre uma função e uma classe. Uma classe exige um pouco mais de memória, exige instanciação do objeto, etc. Uma função apenas recebe os parâmetros e retorna o resultado de forma procedural.

Note também como o ambiente e o modo como utiliza os recursos influencia muito na performance. Vamos aproveitar o exemplo da resposta do @AllanAndrade

**DateTime**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('+3 days'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
/*
tempo: 0.76813006401062 (segundos)
pico memória: 435824 bytes
memória final: 399816 bytes
*/
```

**date()**

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3 days'));
}
/*
tempo: 0.31057095527649 (segundos)
pico memória: 435328 bytes
memória final: 399296 bytes
*/
```

Observe que o custo de memória não muda mesmo com 1 milhão de execuções. Obviamente a classe possui um mecanismo de cache ou otimização interno. Caso contrário, o custo de memória seria muito maior.

O tempo também está há "anos luz" do teste da resposta do Allan. <sub>Como ele não postou como fez os testes, qual o ambiente, etc, não posso comparar com o resultado dele. Também pode ter confundido o tempo de micro, mili ou segundos. Se ele puder deixar mais claro, podemos ter um comparativo mais preciso.</sub>

Agora vamos usar de forma "inteligente", pois, estamos lidando com um objeto e não faz sentido instanciá-lo múltiplas vezes para uma única finalidade. Nesse caso não podemos culpar a linguagem, o ambiente ou ferramentas. A culpa é do programador.

Aqui criamos a instância e setamos o intervalo fora do laço de repetição. Pois isso é o óbvio a se fazer.
No primeiro teste, apesar do uso do DateTime, está incoerentemente usando `strtotime()`. O certo seria usar os próprios recursos da classe.
Para elucidação, usarei a função [date_interval_create_from_date_string()](http://php.net/date_interval_create_from_date_string) a qual é a versão procedural de [DateInterval::createFromDateString()](http://php.net/date_interval_create_from_date_string). Na verdade, é uma alias.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-08-30');
$interval = date_interval_create_from_date_string('3 days');

for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = $date->add($interval)->format('Y-m-d');
}
/*
tempo: 0.18332006645203 (segundos)
pico memória: 436384 bytes
memória final: 400856 bytes
*/
```

Note que agora o "jogo virou" para uma diferença que podemos considerar "brutal". Praticamente metade do tempo comparado com o teste usando a função `date()`.

Para não sermos injustos, vamos otimizar o estilo procedural

```
$interval = strtotime('+3 days');
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $interval);
}
/*
tempo: 0.15265989303589 (segundos)
pico memória: 435376 bytes
memória final: 399344 bytes
*/
```

Ponto para o estilo procedural!!

Ainda assim, considerando uma situação incomum que é executar 1 milhão de vezes, a diferença é muito pequena. Apenas 0.03 microsegundos.

Se aplicarmos uso de otimizadores como o opcache, dentre outros, a diferença pode cair para zero ou até mudar de lado pois os recursos mais recentes possuem funcionalidades que permitem uma melhor otimização. As funções antigas, normalmente não.

Espere! Ainda tem mais!

Uma pequena mudança, usando algo mais apropriado:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-08-30');
$interval = new DateInterval('P3D');

for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $tmp = $date->add($interval);
}
/*
tempo: 0.1128888130188 (segundos)
pico memória: 435824 bytes
memória final: 400040 bytes
*/
```

O jogo virou novamente para classe DateTime.

Uma diferença de 0.04 segundos mais rápido comparado com o melhor desempenho no uso da função `date()` até o momento.

Em relação ao custo de memória, obviamente não mudará, pois a classe possui uma quantidade maior de códigos. Contudo, é um custo irrelevante. O mais relevante aqui, dentro desse contexto dos testes, é a velocidade.

Num resumo geral, a performance depende de um conjunto de fatores. A maior parte é puramente lógica e bom senso no uso das ferramentas.

Podemos pensar que tudo isso são microotimizações, mas como podemos ver, dependendo do como é feito e somatizado com outras rotinas também otimizadas, todas juntas, perfazem uma diferença significativa.

## Considerações

Há de se considerar o contexto sob quais condições será usado o recurso X ou Y. As vezes um simples `date()` formatando qualquer coisa é mais conveniente. Outras vezes você precisa de algo um pouco mais complexo onde o uso das funções procedurais complicam. Nesse ponto entra o bom senso para saber discernir o que é mais adequado. Mantenha em mente o [princípio KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (keep it simple, stupid).

Por terem sido escritas no início da criação do PHP, as funções antigas não possuem padrões adequados comparado com linguagens mais modernas. Para isso, o PHP vem implantando recursos gradualmente como a classe `DateTime` que já está presente na linguagem desde 2004 mas, alguns programadores, devido a disseminação de **desinformação**, simplesmente desconhecem ou ignoram. O tempo de 12 anos não parece muito, mas no mundo da informática é o equivalente a 1 século na vida humana.

A informática evolui muito rápido, e se ficarmos presos em métodos, costumes e achismos, perdemos o fio da meada e ficamos presos numa concepção ultrapassada e muitas vezes, ignorante.

Eu posso mostrar mais exemplos de como otimizar ainda mais ambos os estilos acima, inclusive com uso de otimizadores e cache, mas acredito que os exemplos e explicações acima já deixaram bem claro.

## Como foram realizados os testes?

Um ponto importante é, tudo isso aí rodou sob Windows e PHP como módulo Apache.

Experimente rodar também num ambiente Linux bem configurado com PHP-FPM sob Nginx. Enfim, teste em ambientes diferentes. É bem sabido que PHP como um módulo é menos performático do que como CGI ou esses novos meios como o PHP-FPM.

Importante saber que o benchmark foi feito usando apenas o próprio PHP para simular ao máximo um ambiente web real.

O custo de memória pode ser menor considerando somente a execução dos scripts propostos. O resultado final de custos de memória incluem um pequeno bootstrap e o carregamento de 2 bibliotecas simples para cálculo de tempo de execução e memória.

**O script completo**:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); // & ~E_NOTICE
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

define('CHARSET', 'UTF-8');

ini_set('default_charset', CHARSET);
mb_http_output(CHARSET);
mb_internal_encoding(CHARSET);

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset='.CHARSET);

include 'Bench.php';
include 'Memory.php';

use \Tipui\Libs\Bench as Bench;
use \Tipui\Libs\Memory as Memory;

Bench::Start();

// Aqui coloca o script que deseja testar.

$bench = Bench::Calc();
$memory = Memory::GetData();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($bench);
print_r($memory);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Bench.php**

```
<?php
namespace Tipui\Libs;

class Bench
{

    protected static $ini;

    public static function Start($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the start time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        self::$ini[$id] = microtime(true);
    }

    public static function Calc($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the difference between the start and the end time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        $end = microtime(true);
        $diff = $end - self::$ini[$id];

        /*
        Break the difference into seconds and microseconds
        */
        return array($diff - intval($diff), self::$ini[$id], $end);
    }

}
```

**Memory.php**

```
<?php
namespace Tipui\Libs;

class Memory
{

    private static $data;

    public static function GetData($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the start time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        self::$data[$id]['peak'] = memory_get_peak_usage();
        self::$data[$id]['current_usage'] = memory_get_usage();
        return self::$data[$id];
    }

    public static function Usage($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the start time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        return self::$data[$id]['usage'] = memory_get_usage();
    }

}
```

**Ambiente**

```
SO: Windows 10 pro 64bit
RAM: 2 X 8GB (DDR3)
CPU: Intel i7-4770K @ 3.50GHz
PHP 7.0.5 (módulo)
Apache 2.4.20
```

<sub>(Hardware em setagens padrão do fabricante. Windows, Apache e PHP também em configurações padrão.)</sub>

Comment: Estou aqui a testar com Ubuntu Server 14.04, 8G RAM, i7-3770 @ 3.4GHz, PHP 5.5.9 e apache 2.4.7 e não estou a ter resultados sequer semelhantes aos teus, há grande diferença de uma utilização para a outra.

Comment: Alias, eu fiz agora o teste com 1 milhão e, apesar de ficar à espera do resultado, o resultado é  0.28077387809753, menor do que me aparecia com cem mil. Tens explicação?

Comment: Para 1 milhão de iterações, como obviamente vai passar de 1 segundo, modifique a saída do método `Calc()` na classe `Bench`. Coloque `return array($diff, $diff - intval($diff), self::$ini[$id], $end);`. Provavelmente o seu resultado vai dar uns 4.28 segundos.

Comment: Mesmo assim, eu com cem mil e com [a resposta do Lacobus](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149877/7210) tenho tempos na base dos segundos. Os seus tempos de 0.2 micro segundos são no mínimo irreais. Alguma coisa está mal ai.

Comment: o tempo é esse mesmo em segundos 0.111.....  micro segundos não..

Comment: desculpe, agora que percebi o comentários nos codigos está "microsegundos"...   era para ser "segundos" . Copiei a estrutura de outros testes onde calculei microsegundos e não me atentei. Mas isso é um tanto irrelevante. O importante é a diferença entre `class datetime` e `function date()`. Que ficou comprovado o "mito" nesses testes e como os testes nas outras respostas são mal feitos.