# Como é que podemos obter o tempo de execução de um script?

Tags: php, desempenho

Esta aqui a ler a pergunta [Comparando-se com classe DateTime, a função date é mais performática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149808/7210) e fiz alguns testes com a [resposta do Daniel Omine](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149869/7210), mas obtive resultados que não me pareceram nada fiáveis.

Como é que eu posso obter o tempo de execução de um script PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `microtime()` retorna o *timestamp* atual. Você pode usa-la para "marcar" o tempo inicial e o final do seu *script* a fim de se obter o tempo de execução.

Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
// Armazena o timestamp antes da execucao do script
$tm_inicio = microtime( true ); 

//
// Codigo Script 
//

// Armazena  o timestamp apos a execucao do script
$tm_fim = microtime( true );

// Calcula o tempo de execucao do script 
$tempo_execucao = $tm_fim - $tm_inicio;

// Exibe o tempo de execucao do script em segundos
echo '<b>Tempo de Execucao:</b> '.$tempo_execucao.' Segs';

?>
```

Referência:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.microtime.php

Espero ter Ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo da outra resposta usei isso:

```
class Bench
{

    protected static $ini;

    public static function Start($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the start time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        self::$ini[$id] = microtime(true);
    }

    public static function Calc($id = 0)
    {
        /*
        Get the difference between the start and the end time in microseconds, as a float value
        */
        $end = microtime(true);
        $diff = $end - self::$ini[$id];

        /*
        Break the difference into seconds and microseconds
        */
        return array($diff, $diff - intval($diff), self::$ini[$id], $end);
    }

}
```

Modo de uso

```
// Inicia a contagem. Após essa linha não pode ter nada que não seja relacionado ao que deseja testar.
Bench::Start();

// aqui o bloco de script que deseja testar

// Finaliza a contagem e retorna o resultado.
$bench = Bench::Calc();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($bench);
echo '</pre>';
```

Importante observar que você obteve um resultado inesperado devido a esse techo do retorno da método `Calc()`

```
return array($diff - intval($diff), self::$ini[$id], $end);
```

Esse é o retorno original pois normalmente faço testes que retornam menos de 1 segundo. normalmente de 1000 a 100 mil iterações. Por isso não necessito saber quantidade de segundos.

Para o seu caso, onde você aplicou 1 milhão de iterações, retorne dessa forma:

```
return array(
    $diff, // literal
    $diff - intval($diff), // parte decimal
    self::$ini[$id], // microtime inicial
    $end // microtime final
);
```

Na primeira chave, o valor em segundos.

Nota: Esteja ciente de que são testes dentro do contexto da pergunta original: [Comparando-se com classe DateTime, a função date é mais performática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149808/7210)

Comment: Daniel, mas então se eu usar este novo return também funciona para 100 mil?

Comment: Experimentei agora com 100 mil e com esse novo return, e dá 2.5 segundos, presumo eu, visto que o script demora prai 2 segundos até aparecer o resultado.

Comment: como citei, normalmente faço teste que não passam de 1 segundo.  por isso ignoro o valor de $diff.  No seu caso, como é uma configuração inferior e está passando de 1 segundo, é melhor retor ar o valor de $diff.

Comment: por curiosidade, se possível, teste com PHP7.

Comment: Daniel não sei se é do SO ou do PHP, mas agora em Windows10 com PHP7 já deu valores parecidos com os teus.