# Qual a diferença entre usar ArrayIterator vs Array Simples?

Tags: php, array

Alguns exemplos na net com `ArrayInterator` usa-se das seguintes formas:

```
$arr = array("Banana", "Abacaxi", "Abacate", "Morango");    

// loop through the object
foreach (new ArrayIterator($arr) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

ou

```
$arr = array("Banana", "Abacaxi", "Abacate", "Morango");

$iter = new ArrayIterator($arr);

// loop through the object
foreach ($iter as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Geralmente uso assim:

```
$arr = array("Banana", "Abacaxi", "Abacate", "Morango");

// loop through the object
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Qual a real diferença de performance quando se usa ArrayIterator, não seria mais uma classe a ser instanciada?

A maioria dos exemplos só fala que é uma forma moderna de se programar em OOP, mas não explica, se vai impactar no uso de memória.

Comment: Essa questão sobre consumo de memória/performance depende da finalidade do uso e de como utiliza os recursos. Nessa outra pergunta pode ver como o mal uso influencia na performance. E como o uso correto, dentro de um contexto apropriado, pode resultar numa melhor performance quando trabalha-se com OOP http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149808/comparando-se-com-classe-datetime-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-date-%C3%A9-mais-perform%C3%A1tica/149869#149869

Comment: @DanielOmine Blz, vou da uma olhada, mas gostaria de entender melhor o uso desta, vou da mais uma pesquisada! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em teste de exaustão para verificar a criação de instâncias e posições de memória com o código:

***Observação:*** [*Teste retirado desse link*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php#92214) do site [**php.net**](http://php.net) com modificação para criar instâncias da [classe ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.arrayiterator.php#class.arrayiterator).

```
<?php
echo "<p>".phpversion()."</p>";

for($size = 1000; $size < 50000000; $size *= 2)
{        

    echo "<p>" . "Testing size: $size" . "</p>";

    for($s = microtime(true), $container = Array(), $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        $container[$i] = NULL;
    echo "<p>Array(): " . (microtime(true) - $s) . "</p>";        

    for($s = microtime(true), $container = new ArrayIterator(), $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        $container[$i] = NULL;
    echo "<p>ArrayInterator(): " . (microtime(true) - $s) . "</p>";


    echo "==========================================<br />";
}
```

verifiquei que os resultados ***são minimalistas*** em um modo geral, sendo esse teste realizado com `PHP` ***versão*** `5.6.22` e código retirado do próprio site [**php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php#92214), deu um certa vitória ao tipo [***primitivo do PHP***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.php), o [**array()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), mas, com uma diferença muito pequena:

***PHP versão 5.6.22***

> Testing size: 1000
>
> Array(): 0.00023007392883301
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.00017189979553223
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 2000
>
> Array(): 0.00038886070251465
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.00034308433532715
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 4000
>
> Array(): 0.00078988075256348
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.00084090232849121
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 8000
>
> Array(): 0.0017249584197998
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.0018649101257324
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 16000
>
> Array(): 0.0036230087280273
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.0040380954742432
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 32000
>
> Array(): 0.0067539215087891
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.0051989555358887
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 64000
>
> Array(): 0.0097739696502686
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.011684894561768
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 128000
>
> Array(): 0.021622180938721
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.023998975753784
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 256000
>
> Array(): 0.043958902359009
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.047860860824585
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 512000
>
> Array(): 0.088205814361572
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.097460985183716
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 1024000
>
> Array(): 0.1791729927063
>
> ArrayInterator(): 0.20163583755493
>
> ========================================== Testing size: 2048000

Particularmente, não vi diferenças, claro que uma ***instância*** e mais custosa do que um [**tipo primitivo**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.php). Se precisar de um código mais elaborado e sabe usar a [classe ArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.arrayiterator.php#class.arrayiterator) (saber trabalhar com Orientação Objeto principalmente), pode usar sem medo que isso não vai ser o problema do seu código em relação a desempenho, mas sim um conjunto de fatores:

- gargalo em banco, falta de chaves, índices, etc.
- código mau elaborados, repetição, etc.
- uso indevido das classes e falta de conhecimento em POO.
- códigos desnecessários e irrelevantes para resolver um determinado problema.

Existe, uma classe que pode ser utilizado nas versão ***`>=5.3.0 e 7`*** do PHP a [`classe SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php#class.splfixedarray), pois ela limita o número de itens desse `array`, tendo uma *desvantagem* que seus índices só aceitam números inteiros e sua *vantagem* é sobre a execução ser mais rápida (***desempenho***).

Então, se precisar criar um `array` com índices de *números inteiros*, essa [`classe SplFixedArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php#class.splfixedarray) seria a mais ideal, por ter um desempenho melhor.